# Change cron default sendmail to mail

Tags: cron, freebsd, email

I'm running FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE.

On default cron is using `/usr/lib/sendmail` to send user emails. How can I tell/set cron to use `/bin/mail` instead?

FreeBSD is using the cron version from Paul Vixie, so the `-m` option sets the email receiver not what mailer to use.

I downloaded the FreeBSD source code and tried the command `# make config` in `/usr/src/usr.sbin/cron/`, that ofc does not work since config is not defined. But I think that's an bad idea anyway cause future updates could easy overwrite this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron` by default uses the value of the systemwide `_PATH_SENDMAIL` macro as the expansion of `MAILCMD`, the command to use to send messages generated by jobs. In order to use a different mail program, you need to modify the Makefile to define appropriate values for the `MAILCMD` and `MAILARGS` macros. The Makefile in the source tree includes commented definitions illustrating possible values, but there appears to be a slight bug in the `MAILARGS` macro that applies when `MAILCMD` is defined to be `/bin/mail` - it has two string expansions, but only receives one string when called, so in the patch in the gist, I removed the first of the expansions.

If you have the `patch` utility installed (it's in ports, if not), apply [this patch](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77c125a32bca574e48298ff8b50c3fde) (relative to `/usr/src/usr.sbin/cron`) and build/install cron:

```
% cd /usr/src/usr.sbin/cron
% make 
% make install
```

Restart cron, and you should now be using `/bin/mail`. N.B. this patched version builds cleanly on my system (11-STABLE), but I have not tried using it in place of the default version. Remember that you'll probably need to do this again when you upgrade, since the FreeBSD default is to use `/usr/lib/sendmail`.

Answer (score 2):

The actual path used by `cron` is `/usr/sbin/sendmail` which is defined in `/usr/include/paths.h`. This is usually a symbolic link to [mailwrapper(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mailwrapper).

You can change the default behaviour for all applications by modifying `/etc/mail/mailer.conf`. See [mailer.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mailer.conf) for more.

Of course, your `/bin/mail` would need to have similar semantics to `sendmail` and you would have to be comfortable with changing the default behaviour for `sendmail` on the entire system.